# Can I run an IF statement form the mysql command line? v 5.6

Tags: mysql, if-statement, command, line

SET @credit = 'True';  // This works query ok.

If @credit = 'True' THEN SET @credit = 'False'; // Get an error

SELECT @credit; // can't get this far

Trying to run a mysql IF statement from the console, but can't get the simplest
of statements to work? What am I missing? The error: There is an error near If @credit = True THEN SET @credit = False'

Answer (score 0):

The IF statement is for use in stored procedures.

You can use the IF function:

```
SET @credit='True';
SET @credit=IF(@credit='True','False',@credit);
SELECT @credit;
```

Comment: That gives me some good insight, but that is the IF FUNCTION, not the IF Statement. Tks!

Comment: what is the @credit after False in the IF function doing?

Comment: the IF function produces a value which is used to set `@credit`.  if the test is true, it produces 'False', otherwise it produces `@credit` (setting `@credit` to itself, so leaving it unchanged).

Comment: yes, that's why I said "The IF statement is for use in stored procedures."